# When can CancellationToken.CanBeCanceled be false?

Tags: .net, multithreading, cancellation-token

The documentation on [`CancellationToken.CanBeCanceled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.canbecanceled.aspx) describes what it does, but doesn't mention when it can ever be false. Hence it's not entirely clear to me when I should pay attention to this property.

In which circumstances can it be false and when should I look at it?

Comment: Here's a case where it seems to always be false: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35135119/queuebackgroundworkitem-cancellationtoken-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, [CancellationToken.None](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.none.aspx) returns one that isn't cancellable.

If you're the user of an API that insists on receiving a CancellationToken, but you've got no interest in ever attempting to cancel the work, then you could just pass it this token.

As someone *building* an API, you may be able to make certain optimizations if CanBeCancelled returns false - maybe it's "expensive" for you to check the IsCancellationRequested property.